# Append new data to an existing dataframe (RDS) in R

Tags: r, stream, append, dataframe

I have an Rscript that is reading in a constant stream of data in the form of a flat file.  Another script picks up this flat file, does some parsing and processing, then saves the result as a data.frame in RDS format.  It then sleeps, and repeats the process.

```
saveRDS(tmp.df, file="H:/Documents/tweet.df.rds") #saving the data.frame
```

On the second... nth iteration, I have the code only process the new lines added to the flat file since the previous iteration.  However, in order to append the delta lines to the permanent data frame, I have to read it in, append, and then save it back out, overwriting the original.

```
df2 <- readRDS("H:/Documents/tweet.df.rds") #read in permanent                      
tmp.df2 <- rbind(df2, tmp.df) #append new to existing
saveRDS(tmp.df2, file="H:/Documents/tweet.df.rds") #save it
rm(df2) #housecleaning
rm(tmp.df2) #housecleaning
```

This approach is risky because whenever the RDS is open for reading/writing, another process wanting to touch that file has to wait. As the base file gets bigger, the risk increases.

Is there something like an `appendRDS` (I know literally there isn't) that can achieve what I want- iterative updating of a single data frame- saved to a file- that uses appending rather than complete replacement?

Comment: Well, I think you're doing a bad thing in the first place. You're overwriting your previous data, thus effectively deleting previous versions.  That said, why not just save your data in text form (CSV, e.g.) with `write.table` , which does allow appending to existing documents?

Comment: I'm actually overwriting the previous data with a copy of the previous data rbind'd to the latest records.  Hopefully my second block of shows that process- read in old, append new, overwrite old with old+new.
I now see the write.table append option.  I had stayed away from a non-native format because I figured it would increase processing overhead.  But I may be OK with trading off a little inefficiency in that step for better stability.

Comment: I wonder if some magic with ?serialize could be used to create an append function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can safeguard your process by using connections, opening and closing it before the next process takes over.

```
con <- file("tmp.rds")
open(con)
df <- readRDS(con)
df.new <- rbind(df,df)
saveRDS(df.new, con)
close(con)
```

Update:

You can test if a connection to the file is open and tell it to wait for a bit if you're having problems with concurrency.

```
while(is.Open(con)) { # untested but something of this nature should work
sys.Sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly.  That looks like it would work within the same script.  Would that help protect it if another script (i.e., another process) were accessing that same RDS at the same time?  I'm afraid my only experience with concurrency is with databases, not with files.

Comment: @Brandon-Bertselsen
Worked!  
`#pass1
con <- file("H:/Documents/tweet.df.rds")
 while(isOpen(con)) { 
  Sys.sleep(2)
 }
 open(con, "wb")
 saveRDS(tmp.df, con)
 close(con, type="rw")
#Pass N
con <- file("H:/Documents/tweet.df.rds")
 while(isOpen(con)) { 
  Sys.sleep(2)
 }
 open(con, "rb")
 df2 <- readRDS(con)
 close(con, type="rw")
 tmp.df2 <- rbind(df2, tmp.df)
 
 con <- file("H:/Documents/tweet.df.rds")
 while(isOpen(con)) { 
  Sys.sleep(2)
 }
 open(con, "wb")
 saveRDS(tmp.df2, con)
 close(con, type="rw")` 
Maybe some overkill in the open/closing, but I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with using a series of numbered RDS files in a directory instead of a single RDS file? I don't think is is possible to append to a data frame an an RDS file without rewriting the entire file, since data frames are simply lists of columns, so presumably they are serialized one column at a time, so only the last column ends near the end of the file.

If you want to stick with a single file but minimize the risk of reading inconsistent data from a RDS file, you can read it in, do the append operation, and then write it out to a temp file and rename the temp file to the original name once it is finished. Then at least your period of risk is not dependent on the size of the file. I'm not familiar with what kind of atomicity is guaranteed by various filesystems when renaming a file to an existing name, but it's probably better than the time taken by saveRDS.

Comment: Interesting idea.  It'd take a little smithing to get all the RDS files read in; and then reaching down into the OS to do the drop/rename.  Clever, but beyond my patience ;).

Comment: You can write a function that works as a drop-in replacement for `saveRDS` that writes to a temp file and renames.